# Jupyter in VS Code using wrong version of scipy

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, scipy

In VS Code on Ubuntu, when I run a Jupyter notebook, it is using a different version of scipy from when I run the commands in a terminal, despite the fact that the kernel and interpreters appear to be identical. If I run Jupyter from a terminal, it works correctly. Where can I change this behavior in VS Code? Many thanks!

Comment: what does it say is the python version (in the status bar) when you're in the .py file?

Comment: you could try making a new conda environment and downloading scipy into it and running the same as above in that environment, or uninstall scipy and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Anaconda version of scipy was 1.7.3, so VS Code was seeing the 'right' one, but I had installed scipy version 1.8.0 via pip before installing Anaconda, which for some reason was picked up in the terminal. I removed both and reinstalled scipy using 'python -m pip install scipy', and I now have the most recent version in Anaconda, which is seen both in the terminal and Jupyter in VS Code.